# Angular import Node Package

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, module, package

I cloned this angular project: https://github.com/etherparty/explorer

I want to install another module into it: https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder

I want to use the functions of the npm package now in angular. It doesn't work.

**Steps I took:**

```
npm install ethereum-input-data-decoder
```

Tried if it worked. No!

Then I added the import in row 1 in the transactionInfosController.js file, as I want to use the new module there.

```
import { InputDataDecoder } from '../../ethereum-input-data-decoder';
```

**Programm crashes partially with error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I realised that that I am importing the node package incorrectly.

But looking at the file structure of the cloned git repo I don't see another file where I can import the package.

Where exactly do I need to place the import/which file do I need to create?

EDIT: Need answers for AngularJS

Comment: Are you using the `ethereum-input-data-decoder` package in NodeJS???

Comment: I installed it via npm install ethereum-input-data-decoder

Comment: Trying to get it working in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
import * as inputDataDecoder from 'ethereum-input-data-decoder'
```

Or as Tony pointed out

```
import InputDataDecoder as inputDataDecoder from 'ethereum-input-data-decoder'
```

If you are using angularjs try this:

```
<script src='path_to_node_modules/ethereum-input-data-decoder'></script>
```

And than import it as:

```
angular.module('YourApp', ['InputDataDecoder']);
```

Comment: Not recommend to do this. Import * will import everything to your app

Comment: If you have a look at https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder/blob/master/dist/index.js. `inputDataDecoder ` is the only thing being exported as module so i guess that's fine. or `*` can be replaced with `InputDataDecoder`

Comment: Where do I need to put this? Can I put it here on line 1? https://github.com/etherparty/explorer/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/transactionInfosController.js

Comment: Yes i guess on line 1

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Oh you are using angularjs. You should have added the angularjs tag. anyhow this might work first do `<script src='path_to_node_modules/ethereum-input-data-decoder'>` and than `angular.module('YourApp', ['InputDataDecoder ']);`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. However, I have a slight problem. The node_modules folder is on directory up. using `src='./../node_modules/ethereum-input-data-decoder/dist/index.js'` doesn't make the script find the module. Instead the GET doesn't recognize the `./../`.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You tried just with `src='node_modules/ethereum-input-data-decoder/dist/index.js'` ?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because the node_modules folder is one directory up.

Comment: It should be `index.html` and `node_modules` are always on same level. Can you post your directory structure???

Comment: My structure is defined by this github project: https://github.com/etherparty/explorer
They arent in the same directory level currently

Comment: The project seems to be using bower for package management. You can easily install `ethereum-input-data-decoder` bya dding it in `bower.json` just like other modules and than add that in `index.html` just like a lot of other plugins that have been added in `index.html` file already like
`<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Unfortunately bower doesn't have this package in its index:
`bower ENOTFOUND     Package ethereum-input-data-decoder not found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198289/discussion-between-azzam-asghar-and-pave).